# Automatic backup

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, apache, backup

I need to backup automatically daily my database in mysql and all image files on the server.

Is there a way to backup these things and send it on my email address ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a bash script that contains [gzip](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html), [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) and [mail](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailutils/manual/mailutils.html#mail) commands and have it run daily via cron job.

Comment: That's a good idea. BUT what happens when database and images folder gets too big?

Comment: I've been using shell script+cron to generate mysqldump of a database that's ~750MB in size till date, the sql zips down to ~10MB. The script runs every 8 hours, no problems so far. Can't say anything about files.